# Does SPSS give factor scores for mean subtracted variables?

Tags: regression, spss, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

From the Johnson's book, I can see the orthogonal factor model is as follows:

$X-\mu=LF+\epsilon$

So if I use SPSS for extracting factor scores from a factor analysis of several variables, then am I going to get factor scores for mean subtracted variables? Actually my intention is to use the factor scores as IVs along with some IVs that were not used in the factor analysis, which is, as far as I know is a valid procedure. But if I get estimated values of $F$ (factor scores) from $(X-\mu)$, then what should be done to the IVs which were not included in the factor analysis during regression? What should I do with the DV? Should they also be mean subtracted?

Comment: For main effects in regression ("plain vanilla" coefficients), it makes no difference whether you subtract each score from its mean.  Some people claim that it makes a difference if you're including interaction/moderator effects. Some say the coefficients will come out differently; some, the collinearity diagnostics or the standard errors. And then people will go into special cases when one or another claim is true or untrue.  I've seen so much disagreement in the literature about these things that I've almost completely stopped bothering to mean-center.  My own tests have been inconclusive.

Comment: Thanks rolando2. I was thinking that the regression model is of the form $Y=X\beta+e$. So if $X-\mu=LF+\epsilon$ so that $X=\mu+LF+\epsilon$ then should I think differently.